# Kendo DatePicker Selection ASP.Net

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net, kendo-ui

How do I pass the selected date as a string to a variable using jQuery?

```
<div class="col-md-3">
     @Html.Kendo().DatePicker().Name("SearchDate").Value("").HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:150px", @class = "", @placeholder = "Select Date"})
</div>
```

It seems the data in the text box doesn't appear as a `value=""` in the html once rendered.  I'm not sure how to extract the selected date.

Comment: Try adding an id attribute to HtmlAttributes and then extract the value using the expression : $("datepickerID").val();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation:

[**Get the value**](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/datepicker#methods-value)

```
<input id="datepicker" />
<script>
$("#datepicker").kendoDatePicker({
    value: new Date(2013, 10, 10)
});
//Same as the Name("SearchDate") method
var datepicker = $("#SearchDate").data("kendoDatePicker");

var value = datepicker.value();
console.log(value);
</script>
```

The only difference is that you are creating the kendoDatePicker with Razor, but as long as you access the correct Name (SearchDate) you should be able to access it.

**EDIT**
**In response to your comment**

> This means, once the calender loads, and is then selected, how do you
>   pass it to a variable.

Razor cannot directly interact with javascript variables. IE you cannot set a javascript variable within razor. You can however call a function once the date is selected.

[From the documentation](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/aspnet-mvc/helpers/datepicker/overview#razor---subscribe-by-handler-name)

```
@(Html.Kendo().DatePicker()
  .Name("datepicker")
  .Events(e => e
        .Open("datepicker_open")
        .Close("datepicker_close")
        .Change("datepicker_change")
  )
)
<script>
function datepicker_open() {
    //Handle the open event
}

function datepicker_close() {
    //Handle the close event
}

function datepicker_change() {
    //Handle the change event
}
</script>
```

I've created a [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/fp5memyMSQ7hqY4Tw8Ut). Note that it initializes using jquery syntax, but the Razor controls are simply a wrapper for the jQuery version.

Comment: Wed Sep 24 2014 12:33:57 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time) <-- this is what is returned (instead of the mm/dd/yyyy format).  When you select a new date, it doesn't update either.  Closer though.

Comment: @razorsyntax you did not specify that in your question, you are now able to get the date from the kendoDatePicker. How you format it and what you do with it from here is up to you.

Comment: What I asked was: "How do I pass the **selected date**".  This means, once the calender loads, and then a date is **selected** by the user, how do you pass that user selection, not the default loaded date, to a variable.

Comment: @razorsyntax I've modified my answer